# Regex pattern to match Switch Case statements

Tags: regex

We need to identify and then process switch/case statements in code based on some business rules.

A typical switch statement:

```c
switch (a)
    { 
        case "A": 
        case "B": 
            result = "T"; 
            result1 = "F";
        default: 
            result = "F";
    }
```

I have been able to create two patterns to match the switch body in the first step and the case labels and body in the second step, however I am looking for a single regex which will allow me to extract case labels and bodies.

We do not have nested switches.

Kind regards,

Comment: Do your cases include conditionals or loops?  Even a { in a string will cause a problem.  There is really no way around using a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since switch statements can be nested traditional regexes can't handle them (heck, even the fact that the `{}` can be nested breaks them).  Regexes can only parse [Regular Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).  You need some form of parser to parse languages that are not regular.  Depending on what language you have (it looks like C, but so do a lot of things), there may already be a parser you can use (such as [Sparse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/devel/sparse/) for C).

Comment: Hi, 
We don't have nested switches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to start with but it is far from perfect - the expression does not recognize defaults and the end of the switch statement (and maybe includes some other errors).

```
(?sn:(case (?<label>[^:]+):[ \r\n\t]*)+(?<body>((?!case).)*))
```

**UPDATE**

It will also fail if the body contains `case` as part of a string or an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Chas. Owens is correct in his comment. But for simple cases, you can maybe use the following regex:

```
switch\s*\((?<expression>[^\)]+)\)\s*\{\s*((default(?<case>)|case\s*(?<case>"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|\w+))\s*:\s*(?<body>((?!\s*(case\b|default\b|\}))("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\}]))*)\s*)+\}
```

To use it, the regex engine you're using should support explicit multiple named captures and look-aheads (such as the .NET regex engine). Note that all groups except for the named groups can be made non-capturing, but in order to make the regex easier to understand I didn't add the "?:" at the group start to make them non-capturing groups.

You'll then get one match for each recognized `switch` statement with the following captures:

- expression: the expression used for the switch (1 capture)
- case: the case label, or empty (but a successful capture) for the default
- body: the case body, one for each case

case and body will always come as pairs, so that you can enumerate through the captures.